# resolving a javascript promise

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

Below outlines a promise that has two simple steps display on the console something, then display something else after the first step is completed.

I am trying to understand how to resolve the promise, and allow the 2nd step to complete.

```
var lookup_documents = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("1st");
        //resolve(); - How do I do this outside of this function?
    }

);

lookup_documents.then(
    function() {
        console.log("2nd");
    }
);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the function"? You should not. Just do the first step inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use `new Promise()` when you want to wrap some asynchronous function into a promise, such as:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    makeAjaxCall((err, data) => {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        else return resolve(data);
    })
});
```

There are other Promise implementations, such as `q`, where you can create  a "deferred" object that returns a promise... Something similar would be:

```
function makeAjaxCallPromise() {
    let deferred = Q.defer();
    makeAjaxCall((err, data) => {
        if(err) return deferred.reject(err);
        else return deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

For the specific thing you want... All I can think of is declare a variable outside of the promise function scope and asign it, something like:

```
let resolver, rejecter;
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolver = resolve;
    rejecter = reject;
});
makeAjaxCall((err, data) => {
    if(err) return resolver(err);
    else return rejecter(data);
});
```

But that doesn't look too good and can lead to errors... Try to wrap everything in your Promise function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, using your example - if I understand you correctly.

```
var lookup_documents = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1st");
    resolve();
  });
};

lookup_documents().then(function() {
  console.log("2nd");
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, worked nicely. To further clarify here, I was trying to call a function within the first part of the promise that performed an API call, and wanted to resolve the first part of the promise after the API completed (in a separate function).

Comment: Have you been able to figure that out? Otherwise I can change my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: I took the above suggestion and placed the API in the first part of the promise, then resolve it upon completion of the API call. To initiate the API call, I use the second piece of code provided here with inserted commands to perform based on a successful resolve of the first part of the promise. - Thanks, this made my day!

Comment: Sure, would love to give you credit, how do I do this? I haven't used this board that much.